# Avro Schema Aliases

Tags: schema, alias, avro

I am using two different schemas to write data using Avro. The first one is

```json
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "DynamicFact_aSource",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "user",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "User",
      "namespace" : "foo",
      "fields" : [...]
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "event",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "Event",
      "namespace" : "foo",
      "fields" : [...]
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "aLabel",
    "type" : [ "null", {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "record",
        "name" : "Label",
        "namespace" : "foo",
        "doc" : "* Holds a single string.",
        "fields" : [ {
          "name" : "value",
          "type" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "avro.java.string" : "String"
          }
        } ]
      }
    } ],
    "default" : null
  } ]
}
```

and the second one is

```json
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "DynamicFact_bSource",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "user",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "User",
      "namespace" : "foo",
      "fields" : [...]
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "event",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "Event",
      "namespace" : "foo",
      "fields" : [...]
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "anotherLabel",
    "type" : [ "null", {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "record",
        "name" : "Label",
        "namespace" : "foo",
        "doc" : "* Holds a single string.",
        "fields" : [ {
          "name" : "value",
          "type" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "avro.java.string" : "String"
          }
        } ]
      }
    } ],
    "default" : null
  } ]
}
```

Now I want to read data from these two different schemas into one RDD. In order to do that, I am creating a new - reader - schema like so

```json
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "DynamicFact_multiSourceAggregation",
    "fields":
    [
        {
            "name": "user",
            "type":
            {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "User",
                "namespace": "foo",
                "fields":
                []
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "event",
            "type":
            {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "Event",
                "namespace": "foo",
                "fields":
                []
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "theMultiSourceAttributeLabel",
            "type":
            [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items":
                    {
                        "type": "record",
                        "name": "Label",
                        "namespace": "foo",
                        "doc": "* Holds a single string.",
                        "fields":
                        [
                            {
                                "name": "value",
                                "type":
                                {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "avro.java.string": "String"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "default": null,
            "aliases":
            [
                "aLabel",
                "anotherLabel"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The reader schema defined `user` and `event` exactly the same way as the writers' schemas do but for the 3rd field instead of `aLabel` and `anotherLabel` that the two writer schmas use, I am using another name `theMultiSourceAttributeLabel` and setting aliases for it

```json
"aliases":
            [
                "aLabel",
                "anotherLabel"
            ]
```

so that the reader can match Avro fields with `aLabel` or `anotherLabel` to `theMultiSourceAttributeLabel`. Although the user and event are loaded successfully using the reader's schema, `aLabel` and `anotherLabel` fields are not. This means that all `theMultiSourceAttributeLabel` fields are null.

Should Avro be able to figure out this mapping once provided with the list of aliases? Why are all `theMultiSourceAttributeLabel` in the RDD read null?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the writer schemas have different names. This requires the aliasing of the reader schema name as well - apart from the field name aliasing. So when defining the reader schema one must do

```scala
    def schema(): Schema = {
      val builder = SchemaBuilder
        .record(s"DynamicFact_$name")
        .aliases(getSourceSchemaAliases: _*)
        .fields()
       ...
}
```

this will produce

```json
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "DynamicFact_multiSourceAggregation",
    "fields":[...],
    "aliases":
    [
        "DynamicFact_aSource",
        "DynamicFact_bSource"
    ]
}
```

which is enough for the reader schema to successfully read both writer schemas